# Chrome extension cant see DOM elements

Tags: google-chrome, dom

Hello I saw many tutorials and articles but any of these cant solve my problem.
I have all permisions in manifest.json
I can see button and I can click it, but the alert show null.

This is my popup.html

```
<button id="gdynianka_komentarz_button">Komentarz</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

This is my popup.js

```
function gdynianka_komentarz_click(){
   var t = document.getElementById('tabela_ocen');
   alert(t); // it shows null !
   document.getElementById("gdynianka_komentarz_button").style.color = 'blue';

}
  
   document.getElementById("gdynianka_komentarz_button").addEventListener('click',gdynianka_komentarz_click);
```

Comment: Err... Your popup html doesn't have an element with `id="tabela_ocen"`. So, of course, `t` is `null`.

Comment: I know - this is only popup from my chrome extension. But I want to ge tabela_ocen from page where I'm now.

Comment: Similar to individual tabs, popups each have their own sandboxes. (Backgrounds each have their own sandbox as well.) You use messaging (e.g.: `.sendMessage`) to communicate between the different sandboxes. You'd add a content script to the tab. The popup would pass a message to the background script. The background would pass that on to the tab. The content script would recieve the message and respond with the data needed. Then back through the background script to the popup. (You can go directly from the popup to the content script but closing the popup kills the popup script.)

Comment: A oryginal content is an external page. I can't directly change this content but I want to change it by scrpt in my popup.

Comment: Simplify: I just want to put a content into external input.